# Crashlytics does not disable

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

```
Fabric.with(DataCollectionSettingsActivity.this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(!value).build()).build());
```

Not working for me I want to disable Crashlytics but it does not disable even crashing report has disabled.

Comment: What's `value`? What do you call "disabled Crashlytics"? Throw an exception, check if it's reported.

Comment: I want that crashlystics will not show the crash on Firebase panel if I have disabled it and i have used Fabric.with(DataCollectionSettingsActivity.this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(!value).build()).build());

Comment: @DronaTomar are you looking to disable Crashlytics for specific build types or based on a flag set prior to the Fabric init?

Comment: yes @Mike Bonnell... I have tried but crashlytics still show the crashes

Comment: Sorry, I'm still unclear. How are you trying to disable Crashlytics?

Comment: @Mike Bonnell I am using Fabric.with(DataCollectionSettingsActivity.this, new Crashlytics.Builder().core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(!value).build()).build()); to disable the crashlytics But it does not work for me